# Objects and arrays in PHPlot MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, datetime, object

I trying to do a graphic with PHPPLOT (MYSQLPHP)

The output for the graphic is NULL(vardump of variable dados)

When in database

```
id  utilizador  password    email         nivel ativo   registado

1   cris        xxxxxxxx    cris@cris.com 1     1       2014-05-04 104153
```

I put in bold the fields i need for do the graphic.

```
php

require(phplot-6.1.0phplot.php);


#Também delimitamos uma altura e largura do gráfico
$grafico = new PHPlot(750,600);

$grafico-SetFileFormat(png);


$grafico-SetTitle(NSMF);
$grafico-SetXTitle(Meses);
$grafico-SetYTitle(Utilizadores);


function getValues(){
  $db = new mysqli(xxxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);
  $db-set_charset(utf8);
  $query = $db-query(SELECT COUNT(id) AS id,registado FROM utilizadores GROUP BY YEAR(registado), MONTH(registado) );


  while($obj = $query-fetch_object()){


function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

   $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
   $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
   return  $launch;
}

$exp1 = multiexplode(array( ,-), $registado );

$months = array(January,February, March, April, June, July, August);
echo Month .$months[intval($exp1[1])];

$values[] = array($obj-exp1, $obj-id);

  return $values;
  }

}
```

Is giving one month more... like if is 02 is giving March

The output is null when need to give the count of id group by year and month.

Comment: php arrays are `0` based, so `$months[2]` is `March`. Try `echo Month .$months[intval($exp1[1])-1];`

Comment: thanks, that  resolve that question. Now  the most important is the output of that in graphic is null. When need to give me Month and Year. The datetime convert to month and year because is a datetime and the graphic not recognize that.